# Powershell check storage on remote pc

Tags: powershell, menu, remote-access

Hello I am building a menu to run scripts per option selected and an option I want is to check storage of a remote pc but from researching I have broken the script and hopefully can get assistance from someone that has more than my month experience using PS.

```
Invoke-Command $Computer = Read-Host Please Enter Host name  -ScriptBlock{Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select SystemName, DeviceID, @{n='Size(GB)';e={$_.size / 1gb -as [int]}},@{n='Free(GB)';e={$_.Freespace / 1gb -as [int]}}} > C:\DiskInfo_output.txt
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command $Computer = Read-Host Please Enter Host name` should be `Invoke-Command (Read-Host Please enter....) -ScriptBlock...`

Comment: I found       get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Computername   however am not able to make it so I can input the pc name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `$Computer = Read-Host ...` statement out of the `Invoke-Command` statement:

```
# Ask for computer name
$Computer = Read-Host "Please Enter Host name"

# Invoke command on remote computer
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select SystemName, DeviceID, @{n='Size(GB)';e={$_.size / 1gb -as [int]}},@{n='Free(GB)';e={$_.Freespace / 1gb -as [int]}}
} > C:\DiskInfo_output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Invoke-Command` seeing as the WMI cmdlets accept a `-ComputerName` value:

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter Host name"
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" -ComputerName $ComputerName | 
    Select-Object -Property SystemName, DeviceID, @{
        Name ='Size(GB)';
        Expression = {
            $_.size / 1gb -as [int]
        }
    }, @{
        Name ='Free(GB)';
        Expression = {
            $_.Freespace / 1gb -as [int]
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can have the Computer Name input be prompted first using the grouping operator (*as [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out in the comments*):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" -ComputerName (Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter Host name")
```

- Same goes for the subexpression operator which just tells PowerShell to ask for it first - *without going into more detail*.

---

**Side Note:**

The WMI Cmdlets such as `Get-WMIObject` are deprecated and have been replaced by the newer [CIM Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/?view=powershell-7.2).

- Introduced in v3, it uses a separate remoting protocol other than DCOM.

  - *This can be explicitly made to use DCOM as well, but not by default.*
- Emphasis on **replaced** as they are no longer part of PowerShell's deployment as of PowerShell Core.
- Most cmdlets translate fairly easy if I may add:

  - `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"`
  - `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"`

Comment: Would you know what I am doing wrong in the below I cannot get it to display once I  pick the selection and input the computer I want to check.

Comment: Function Menu 
{
    Clear-Host        
    Do
    {
        Clear-Host                                                                       
        Write-Host -Object 'Please choose an option'
        Write-Host     -Object '**********************'
        Write-Host -Object 'Scripts to run' -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host     -Object '**********************'
        Write-Host -Object '1.  Ping PC '
    Write-Host -Object ''
        Write-Host -Object '2.  Restart ELP Desktops '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object '3.  Restart NOVI Desktops '

Comment: Write-Host -Object ''
  Write-Host -Object '4.  Check PC Storage '
    Write-Host -Object ''
        Write-Host -Object 'Q.  Quit'
        Write-Host -Object $errout
        $Menu = Read-Host -Prompt '(0-4 or Q to Quit)'
 
        switch ($Menu) 
        {
           1 {
                $Computer = Read-Host Please Enter Host name
  Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computername $Computer | `
  Where-Object {$_.IPEnabled -match "True"} | `
  Select-Object -property DNSHostName,ServiceName,@{N="DNSServerSearchOrder";
              E={"$($_.DNSServerSearchOrder)"}}

Comment: ,
              @{N='IPAddress';E={$_.IPAddress}},
              @{N='DefaultIPGateway';E={$_.DefaultIPGateway}} | FT 
              pause
            }
            2 
            {
                restart-computer -ComputerName 
            }
            3 
            {
     restart-computer -ComputerName JYPRBM2-BCP3 -force
            }
     4
     {   # Ask for computer name
   $Computer = Read-Host "Please Enter Host name"
   Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size |pause
     }
            Q

Comment: {
                Exit
            }   
            default
            {
                $errout = 'Invalid option please try again........Try 0-4 or Q only'
            }
 
        }
    }
    until ($Menu -eq 'q')
}   
 
# Launch The Menu
Menu

Comment: @Hola_amigo06, not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: The code is all for a menu and the option to get the storage amount on C drive of an input computer is not working as needed. When I input a domain pc I do not get to see displayed the information  rather due to the end of it I get the output file but would like for it to simply show on the ps screen. If that makes sense sorry new to here